# Bind custom event to JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, events, object, binding

I can't figure out how to do it. It would seem to be something like this:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.fireEvent("myEvent");
}
```

And then in a separate JavaScript file:

```
var obj = new MyObject();
obj.addEventListener("myEvent", function() {
    alert("Event Fired");
});
```

But of course it doesn't work. My question is, how would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: Are you asking, how you could do event binding/triggering in JavaScript or are you struggling with a specific set of tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you're firing the event immediately in the constructor (before the event listener is attached).  Try moving the firing logic into a separate function.

**Update**:

Also, it seems like you're not firing an event properly.  See [this article](http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly) for more information on how to properly fire events in a cross-browser manner.  From that article:

```
function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
        // dispatch for IE
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
        // dispatch for firefox + others
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I implemented the portion for Firefox et al (I'm not targeting IE at all). However from that article it seems that the 'element' variable needs to be a DOM object. In my case it's not, it's a JavaScript object. I tried using "this.initEvent(..." but no luck.

Comment: That is an unfortunate limitation.  As a workaround, you could fire the custom event from the `body` element and listen for the event from the same.